# Updating my table's datagridviewcomboboxcolumns directly

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

*[Note : I've simplified my example for clarity]*

Let's say that I have a Sqlite database with two tables: Items and Sectors:

**Items**:

```
id_items : INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
name_item : VARCHAR(...)
id_sector : INTEGER
```

**Sectors**:

```
id_sector : INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
name_sector : VARCHAR(...)
```

I currently have a datagridview that is bound to the **Items** table. It gets fed alright, and the table displays the sector as a datagridviewcomboboxcolumns.

Hence, in my Winforms CustomControl, I have all the data loading and binding that occurs in the load() method:

```
colSector.DataSource = m_dataContext.SectorTable;
colSector.DisplayMember = "name_sector";
colSector.ValueMember = "id_sector";
ItemsGrid.DataSource = new DataView(m_dataContext.ItemsTable);
```

The comboboxes of my dataview are well loaded with the data from the **Sectors** table.

I now would like a button on my form that would allow the creation of a new sector:

I created a txtbox (txtNewSector) and a button that triggers the creation:

```
    private void btnAddNewSector_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add new sector to db
        m_dataContext.AddNewSector(newSectorName);

        // refresh dataview so that comboboxes are updated with the new entry
        ???
    }
```

How can I perform that refresh?

I hope the edit made the question more clear, please advise....

best regards

Comment: Could it be that AddNewSector writes to the database without updating the data context? Normally, by binding to a DataView, if a new record is added to the underlying table the items grid should be automatically updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
???
```

add

```
ItemsGrid.DataSource = new DataView(m_dataContext.ItemsTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `timer` for that. It will accomplish the task after a certain time interval.

Have a look at the example [Timer in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp11302005054911AM/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp.aspx).

You will find the idea of using it.

I am give some rough sketch

```
private DataTable LoadData()
{
  DataTable  dt  = LoadDatabaseData();

  return dt;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

   myDataGrid.DataSource = LoadData();

   myDataGrid.Databind();

         or 

  your combo box's datasource what ever.

}
```

Note- you are using SQLite regarding which I don't have any idea apart from it is a database. I have only showed you how to call the function that will be the datasource for your grid and after every 1 sec(I mean what ever time interval you specify) the datawill be refreshed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I was misunderstood. I'm looking for the **code** that will update the current view so that the comboboxes bound to a database entry that has changed get updated.

Comment: Make a Function that will load the data from the database and will bound to the grid.
Now call the function from the timer's tick event say after every 1 minute.